# How to add table rows dynamically with Angular?

Tags: angular

I have a table and I want to show rows to existing table when click "Show More"

```
|-----------------------|
| ID   | Name  | Address|
|-----------------------|
| 1    | Sally | CA     |
|-----------------------|
| 2    | Jim   | MA     |
|-----------------------|
 Show More
```

When clicking "Show More" show another rows

```
|-----------------------|
| ID   | Name  | Address|
|-----------------------|
| 1    | Sally | CA     |
|-----------------------|
| 2    | Jim   | MA     |
|-----------------------|
| 3    | Tim   | TX     |
|-----------------------|
|   4  | Sue   | MA     |
|-----------------------|
```

Can I use like

```
<table>
 <ng-container #container></ng-container>
</table>
<button (click)="showMore()">Show More</button>

@ViewChild('container', {read: ViewContainerRef}) container: ViewContainerRef;

showMore() {
   const componentFactory =  
         this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(Component);
   const component = container.createComponent(componentFactory);
}
```

Comment: You can show more elements simply by adding more items to the array that is used in *ngFor for creating the table.

Comment: I want to append data to existing data in table. I don't want to render whole table data again.

Comment: It won't render the whole table again if you use `trackby` in the `*ngFor`. See this for more information: https://netbasal.com/angular-2-improve-performance-with-trackby-cc147b5104e5

Answer (score 0):

> As per @NTP & @DeborahK mentioned in their comments, you can add more rows in the table without re-rendering the whole table using `trackBy`. The demonstration of the same is live **[here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-add-rows-without-refresh)** for your scenario.